# Select2 and Datetimepicker does not work in cloned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, datetimepicker

I clone div with jquery which contains textarea, select2 and datatimepicker.
But cloned select2 and datetimepicker is not working.

```
<div id= "myDiv">
    <textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
    <select class="mySelect2">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">1</option>
    </select>
    <div class="date date-picker" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
        <input type="text" readonly></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also added  `$('.date-picker').datepicker();` and `$(".mySelect2").select2();` into my javascript code.

```
function create() {
    $("#myDiv  div:first").clone().find("textarea select input").each(function () {
        $(this).val('');
    }).end().appendTo("#myDiv");
}
```

Comment: you need to initialize them

Comment: I used jQuery(document).ready(function () { $('.date-picker').datepicker(); $(".mySelect2").select2();})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reinitialize the elements after you clone them.
So in the create function add the two lines below

```
function create() {
    $("#myDiv  div:first").clone().find("textarea select input").each(function () {
        $(this).val('');
    }).end().appendTo("#myDiv");

    $('.date-picker').datepicker(); 
    $(".mySelect2").select2();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked but with datatimepicker and  also with select2 but select2 dublicated. First one is does not work second is work fine. I must delete first one.

Comment: Is it possible to make select2 without dublicate clone?

Comment: You can either not add the class when the original HTML loads, or in your create function do a call to destroy to remove the previous one $('#mySelect2').select2('destroy');

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize those plugins on newly added elements since those elements weren't there(in DOM) when you initialized(within the document ready handler).

```
function create() {
    // cache the element reference
    let $ele = $("#myDiv  div:first").clone().find("textarea select input").each(function () {
        $(this).val('');
    }).end().appendTo("#myDiv");

    // get select and input element and initialize corresponding plugin
    $ele.filter('.date-picker').datepicker(); 
    $ele.filter(".mySelect2").select2();
}
```